# Perform CDC on CLOB Column in Informatica/Teradata

Tags: teradata, informatica, clob, cdc, scd

I have a clob column and I need to perform CDC on it to flag it for update/insert/nochange based on the change in the CLOB data.  My source/Target are teradata. ETL tool we are using is informatica.  I need to perform CDC on this CLOB column.  My table will have one Key column and this CLOB column, i.e., 2 columns.

Could any one help me how can I achieve this scenario either in Teradata or informatica or using both.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be to go for MD5. Load data and store MD5 hash. Upon reload, calculate MD5 and compare with stored one. Direct CLOB comparison might be troublesome and time and memory consuming.

I've found few more comments and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110587/sql-how-do-you-compare-a-clob), take a look.