# How to Compare Two Columns and Display the difference in a new Column - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to compare two columns of type nvarchar and show the output in a new column, is there a way to achieve this in Microsoft SQL Server?

Example:

```
COL1                                    COL2
--------------------                    -----------------------------------
This is my test case                    This is not my test Case, leave me alone


OUTPUT
---------------------
not, leave me alone
```

Comment: "Display the difference" is a very vague description of what you're trying to do. What if it would say "This is This is not my test..." for example. Please write a proper description, and also what you've tried so far.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a datatype `CLOB`.... what **actual** datatype are you using here??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - How do you compare a CLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110587/sql-how-do-you-compare-a-clob)

Comment: Oracle's `CLOB` type [appears](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/datatypes/clob) to be equivalent to T-SQL's `NVARCHAR(MAX)` type. Besides that, I find the example confusing. Are you comparing words individually or are you "subtracting" `COL1` from `COL2` from left to right (and does the output have to be in the original order)? Are capitals important (`case` <> `Case`) and why is `my` in the expected output (`me` <> `my`)?

Comment: @sander, sorry there was a typo in my expected output, I've corrected it. I want to compare words between two column and display the difference in new column

Comment: @marc_s you are right, yes MS SQL doesn't have CLOB, I have DBs in both oracle and MS SQL, I want to achieve this in MS SQL wrongly I referred to column type in oracle, correct column type nvarchar

Comment: @JamesZ all what I've tried and searched so far in internet is not even close to what I was expecting, I tried using DIFFERENCE function, however adding that would not help this discussion. So I didn't add that to my Qs.

Comment: One solution would be to split `col1` and `col2` values into separate words with `string_split()` but this would produce `case` and `Case,` which will not be excluded as the same word. And yet the `,` has to be part of the result... The alternative would be to parse both `col1` and `col2` values from left to right and remove any common characters in the order of their occurrence, `case` + `Case,` would then produce `,` but `abc def`+ `abcz def` will produce `z`... Do you really need that `,` in the result??

Comment: @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh nope this doesn't answer my qs.

Comment: @sander - comma (,) can be removed as common tokens at this stage.

Comment: (1) I don't fully follow the rules that are used for the transformation.  (2) SQL is probably not the right tool for such string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below works one way: `col1` words are removed from `col2`.

**Sample data**

```
create table test
(
  id int,
  col1 nvarchar(max),
  col2 nvarchar(max)
);

insert into test (id, col1, col2) values
(1, 'This is my test case', 'This is not my test Case, leave me alone');
```

**Solution**

```
with cte as
(
  select t.id,
         replace(s.value, ',', '') as word
  from test t
  cross apply string_split(t.col2, ' ') s
    except
  select t.id,
         replace(s.value, ',', '')
  from test t
  cross apply string_split(t.col1, ' ') s
)
select string_agg(c.word, ' ') as result
from cte c
group by c.id;
```

**Result**

```
result
------------------
alone leave me not
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=b1cdf3b4694464fc6bcf05e9873a61e3) to see things in action with intermediate results.

---

**New solution**

Perhaps this version does not look so clean, but it should preserve the word order...

```
with cte as
(
  select t.id,
         row_number() over(order by (select null)) as sort,
         replace(s.value, ',', '') as word
  from test t
  cross apply string_split(t.col2, ' ') s
  where not exists ( select 'x'
                     from test t
                     cross apply string_split(t.col1, ' ') s2
                     where replace(s2.value, ',', '') = replace(s.value, ',', '') )
)
select string_agg(c.word, ' ') within group (order by c.sort) as result
from cte c
group by c.id;
```

**New result**

```
result
------------------
not leave me alone
```

[New fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=2c947b6ca03899805251ba80a64f5676).

Comment: Thanks Sander, is it possible to retrieve the result in the same order as it appears in COL2? like "not leave me alone"

Comment: Answer updated with a new version that maintains the word order.